# Visual Studio 2010: impossible to add features

Tags: visual-studio-2012, installation

On Windows 8.1, I installed Visual Studio 2010, then updated to SP1 + Windows Update fixes and installed Python Tools for Visual Studio 2.1.

Now, I wanted to add a feature to my VS2010 installation. Unfortunately the setup fails with the message:

```
A selected drive is no longer valid.  Please review your installation path settings before continuing with setup.
```

In the installation log I find the following message:

```
[01/23/15,18:45:12] VS70pgui: ***ERRORLOG EVENT*** : Unable to retrieve the install directory for Microsoft Visual Studio Performance Collection Tools for v4.0 in COptionsPage::IsGoodAllComponenentsPath
[01/23/15,18:45:12] vs70uimgr: Entering DisplayMessage() method.
[01/23/15,18:45:12] vs70uimgr: DisplayMessage_START:A selected drive is no longer valid.  Please review your installation path settings before continuing with setup.
[01/23/15,18:45:17] vs70uimgr: DisplayMessage_END:A selected drive is no longer valid.  Please review your installation path settings before continuing with setup.
[01/23/15,18:45:17] VS70pgui: A selected drive is no longer valid.  Please review your installation path settings before continuing with setup.
```

I have not installed the `Microsoft Visual Studio Performance Collection Tools for v4.0` manually at all. *(However, during the installation I was informed that the kernel driver for CPU polling was incompatible with Windows 8.)*

I already tried uninstalling PTVS 2.1 but that did not help either. Any hints on how to get around this issue?

Comment: uninstall everything.

Comment: Absolutely.  How else do you expect to fix weird crap like this?  Hack and slash everything.  Core it out.  You can try reinstalling VS over the original, which works sometimes with some issues.  Whenever has a bum install ever been solved otherwise?

Answer (score 3):

## Scenario

1. Installed VS 2010 and MS SQL SERVER 2012 (BI)
2. Update to VS 2010 SP1
3. Add Feature to VS 2010 i.e. MS SQL 2008 Express Server

## Ambiguous Error

> A Selected Drive is No Longer Valid

## Solution

**Options** [(source)](https://edeevans.wordpress.com/category/development-tipstricks/)

1) Full uninstall of VS 2010, reinstall with the required component(s), then reinstall SP1.

2) Remove SP1 for VS 2010. Install the necessary components, and then install SP1 again.

**For Option 2**

When uninstalling SP1, if you are prompted for the MSI for `vs_setup.msi`:

Search your MS SQL 2012 ISO for the installer, i.e. `F:\1033_ENU_LP\redist\VisualStudioShell\VSSetup`

## Digging Further

**cmd.exe**

```
echo %TEMP%
C:\Users\<user>\AppData\Local\Temp
```

**VS Install Log**

```
C:\Users\<user>\AppData\Local\Temp\dd_install_vs_vstscore_100.txt
```

*Unable to retrieve the install directory for Microsoft Visual Studio Performance Collection Tools for v4.0*

```
VS70pgui: ***ERRORLOG EVENT*** : Unable to retrieve the install directory for Microsoft Visual Studio Performance Collection Tools for v4.0 in COptionsPage::IsGoodAllComponenentsPath
vs70uimgr: Entering DisplayMessage() method.
vs70uimgr: DisplayMessage_START:A selected drive is no longer valid.  Please review your installation path settings before continuing with setup.
```